# Magento 2.4.5 | GraphQL endpoint returns 404 | module-graph-ql packages not installed

Tags: composer, magento2.4.5, graphql, vendor, composer.json

I'm facing an issue where my 2.4.5 `https://<magentostore>/graphql` endpoint is returning a 404. After some research it seems that none of the Magento GraphQl packages are installed by composer. My store is running on Magento 2.4.5 for some time now. This issue is present on both my development and production server.

My `composer.json` file contains all of the GraphQl modules within the "replace" object. Taken from the default Magento 2.4.5 `composer.json` file.

No errors come up during `composer install`. I've tried removing the vendor folder and re-installing all packages. As shown in my screenshot, the `magento/module-graph-ql` is also present in my `composer.lock` file.

I'm guessing this is not entirely Magento related, since it is about missing packages in my vendor folder. But the odd thing about this is, none of the Magento GraphQl packages are installed. Magento itself is running fine on 2.4.5 for some time already. So apparently it's fine that it is missing GraphQL core files.

Any suggestions on how to debug why packages listed in the `package.lock` are not actually installed in the vendor folder?

I'm also not using any modules to disable Magento core modules.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Packages showing in composer.lock, but not present in vendor folder]

[image: 404 error showing, as it if is just a mistyped cms page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Magento Stack Exchange!

You have accidentally used configuration to remove composer packages for GraphQL, where the package config is located in the `replace` node and the version is set to `*`:

```
"replace": {
    "magento/module-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-graph-ql-cache": "*",
    ...
}
```

To bring GraphQL composer packages back to your project, you need to remove these configurations and run the command

```
composer install
```

After that, you must run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`, recompile code, and redeploy static content.

Comment: If you had any issues related to this topic, feel free to let me know. I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks. This was indeed the problem. Guess I'm still not entirely sure if I understand the replace object. Why does the default Magento 2.4.5 composer.json have **"magento/module-graph-ql": "100.4.5"** and **"magento/module-graph-ql-cache": "100.4.2"** defined? And why does removing these lines entirely solve the issue in my case?

Comment: The config for the **composer.json** file is **different** between the source code in the Github repository vs the source code you installed via composer. Setup Magento using the GitHub repository is recommended for contributors who submit the changes to Magento core via the Magento GitHub Repository. Regarding your case, your config is **"magento/module-graph-ql": "*"** instead of a specific version, that why this package was removed.